# Spammed by display popup

Tags: display

I just installed Ubuntu studio on my old laptop to use for photography and music.

But, I get spammed by a window with display settings every like 30 seconds, so the OS is pretty much unusable.

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

https://ibb.co/h240TPv

Comment: if you copied and pasted the spam into your question it may help others identify it.

Comment: Image link added in original post

Comment: Looks like you told the system to try new display settings, but have not accepted the changes after 30 seconds of testing, so the changes are reverting.

Comment: I don't do anything on startup, and this message is just coming up from out of nowhere. Seems like it thinks there is an external display connected or something but there isn't

Comment: What's going on with your top panel? There are a bunch of icons displayed there.

Comment: Yes, they are all the same as the window you see.